# undefined index error with isset() in place?

Tags: php, isset, undefined-index

Have I missed something here that I'm not seeing that would throw an undefined index error for this code? In testing a addition of code to functions.php where `$_POST['sub']` is not being passed it throws the undefined index error below, but this same `isset()` test against the exact same POST variable "sub" is performed about 12 times above line 494 without throwing error. What am i missing?

**ERROR FROM PHP**

> Notice: Undefined index: sub in
>   /home/path/public_html/dtest/includes/functions.php on line 494

**CODE FOR LINE 494**

```
if (isset($_POST['sub']) && $_POST['sub'] == "ritem") {
    $id = $_POST['ritemid'];
    unset($_SESSION['cart']['items'][$id]);
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."");
    die();
} else {
    echo $_POST['sub'];
}
```

Comment: You have to use the isset first, and then check to see if it is "ritem"

Comment: @Chitowns24 But his error says undefined index **sub** - me thinks this isn't all the code

Comment: Yeah, I just re-looked at it I agree

Comment: @MikeB  Thats all the code for it, but answer below is correct - now that i look at it from top to bottom the ELSE part of that statement should have been removed some time back. Looks like it got left in there.

Comment: This is why there's line-length limits and standards disallowing one-line control structures. Clean code looks like this http://codepad.org/BTGPtnbE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `echo $_POST['sub'];` from the `else` part which is responsible for this `Undefined index notice` and replace with the `echo` statement.

Should be like this..

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['sub']) && $_POST['sub']=="ritem") {
    $id=$_POST['ritemid'];
    unset ($_SESSION['cart']['items'][$id]);
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."");die();}
else
{
 echo "The subject is not set";    
}
```

That is because.. when the `if` fails which means the `$_POST['sub']` is not set , so when it comes to the `else` part , you are trying to output `$_POST['sub']` which was *actually* not set (**which is actual source of this problem**)

Comment: Thanks - after looking it back over the ELSE statement should have been removed at an earlier revision and someone overlooked it and left in it. Removing it fixed the issue - sorry it was such a trivial thing, guess I was just as guilty of overlooking it as the other developers

Answer (score 0):

Its because of else case

```
if (isset($_POST['sub']) && $_POST['sub']=="ritem") {
  $id=$_POST['ritemid'];
  unset ($_SESSION['cart']['items'][$id]);
  header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."");
  die();
} else if(isset($_POST['sub'])) {
  echo $_POST['sub'];
} else {
  // Do something else here
}
```